# Overlay the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used Below Code for toggle It's Working Fine But Below Div also goes down when ever we click. Instead of that i want to Overlay(Z-index) of the div when user click it shows dropdown not a Toggle How to i acheive this

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('dd').hide()
  $(".navigation dt").click(function() {
    if ($(this).next('dd').is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow').toggleClass('close');
    } else {
      $(this).next('dd').slideToggle('slow').toggleClass('close');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You should add your html code, if you need further advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the `position` attribute of your dropdown elements, using `position: absolute`.

I have created a very basic example using a dropdown `position: absolute` positioned relative to its parent, using `position: relative`:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="button"><!-- dropdown toggle --></div>
  <div id="subcontent">
    <!-- dropdown content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a suggestion for a jQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide the div '#subcontent'
  $('#subcontent').hide();
  //create click function for subcontent
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('#subcontent').stop().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

<kbd>[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/d8bzac2y/3/)</kbd>

To use these its important to understand position attributes. You can read about it [**at w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).